# Identify the range the values in a worksheet and paste them in a different sheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a Pivot table whose row number could change depending on the data. I want to copy the pivot table and paste it as values starting from column B in another existing sheet.

To do this, i first tried getting the name of the pivot and stored it in a named range using the following code:

```
Sub ListPivotsInfor()
    Dim St As Worksheet
    Dim NewSt As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim I, K As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set NewSt = Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "ListOfPivotTables"
    I = 1: K = 2
    With NewSt
        .Cells(I, 1) = "Name"
        .Cells(I, 2) = "Sheet"
        .Cells(I, 3) = "Location"
        For Each St In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each pt In St.PivotTables
                I = I + 1
                .Cells(I, 1).Value = pt.Name
                .Cells(I, 2).Value = St.Name
                .Cells(I, 3).Value = pt.TableRange1.Address
            Next
        Next
        .Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim RangeName As String
Dim CellName As String

'Single Cell Reference (Workbook Scope)
  RangeName = "PivotName"
  CellName = "A2"

  Set cell = Worksheets("ListOfPivotTables").Range(CellName)
  ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell
```

I later tried to copy the pivot table and paste it in another sheet using the following code:

```
Worksheets.Add
  ActiveSheet.Name = "GEP"

  Worksheets("GEP Write").PivotTables(PivotName).TableRange2.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("GEP").Range("B1")
```

The last line is throwing a "Run time error 1004: Unable to get the PivtoTables property of the worksheet class".

Appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: When referring to named ranges, you plug them in as strings. Ex,: PivotTables("PivotName")

Comment: @DavidG: I tried that initially, didn't work. Is there a way in vba to find the range of the pivot and then copy the values in that range and paste it in another sheet?

Comment: If you paste as values, which is absolutely possible, you will lose the pivot table. Also "PivotName" Is the name of a cell here, not the name of the pivot table. You only names a cell - so it fails when you try to refer to that name like it was the table.

Comment: The best thing to do would be naming your pivot as soon as you create it, and then do what you were doing with the paste. To access the pivot table by its range, use: `Range("PivotName").PivotTable.Name` in the even that the range is called "PivotName"  MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837826.aspx

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for your help. It worked.